# How to download ERA-Interim data from the ECMWF data archive using R?

Tags: r, download

I am now working on the ERA-Interim daily precipitation data and I want to download the data in a programming way so I do not need to download the data one by one.

I have found a tutorial on how to download the data using Python https://software.ecmwf.int/wiki/display/CKB/How+to+download+ERA-Interim+data+from+the+ECMWF+data+archive, however, as I am not familiar with Python, I wonder if there is any way to use R instead?

Comment: You can run `python` code within `R` w/ `reticulate` package https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/introduction.html

Comment: @Tung Thank you for your help. Could you provide more details so I can accept your answer?

Comment: I can't as I've never tried running Python in R before. You will need to try it for yourself. Hopefully you can provide an answer afterward here to help future readers. GL!

Comment: @Tung Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ecmwfr package in R